# nestjs exported const variable reference error

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

config.ts

```
export const ApiConfig = {
  ApiKey: process.env.TEST_API_KEY,
  ApiSecret: (process.env.STAGE === 'PROD') ? 'prod_key' : 'local_key'
}
```

service.ts

```
import { ApiConfig } from '../config'

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  constructor() { }

  private readonly API_KEY = ApiConfig.ApiKey;
  private readonly SECRET_KEY = ApiConfig.ApiSecret;

  async func1() {
    const params = {
      property1: this.API_KEY,
      property2: this.SECRET_KEY,
    }
    ....
    return result;
  }
}
```

as above
The const object defined in config.ts is used in service.ts.

property1 has undefined value,
property2 has 'prod_key' or 'local_key' value

When debugging, process.env.TEST_API_KEY has a value but
ApiConfig has 'uncaught referenceError'

Why?

Strangely, not in the local environment
In the ec2 instance, both properties have expected value.

Comment: Are you using `dotenv`? If so, where and when? If not, how is `TEST_API_KEY` supposed to be set?

Comment: The dotenv file is being used.
just not posted
TEST_API_KEY is defined in dotenv file

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood nestjs as nextjs?

Comment: d'oh, I certainly did. My apologies

Comment: In that case, have you read the documentation on [ConfigModule](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)?

Comment: I referred to the documentation for initial setup.
I'm not sure if it's a configmodule issue
When I checked through debugging, the value is definitely being received from env.
Why can't read the exported variable ApiConfig in func1?

Comment: Probably because the code in `config.ts` is evaluated before `dotenv` has parsed `.env` files. Notice how in [this example](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files) the custom config exports a function and not a static object

Comment: thank you
Then why does property2 contain a value?
Does putting a value in ApiSecret in ApiConfig using a ternary operator have any effect?